# Hibernate SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement ...Column "NON" not found

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal_admin")
public class TerminalAdmin {
        @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "admin_role", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", nullable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", 
                    nullable = false) })
   private Set<AdminRole> adminRoles;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal_admin_role")
public class AdminRole {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id", sequenceName = "user_id")
    private Long adminId;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public AdminRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public AdminRole() {
    }

    public Long getAdminId() {
        return adminId;
    }

    public void setAdminId(Long adminId) {
        this.adminId = adminId;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof AdminRole)) {
            return false;
        }

        AdminRole adminRole = (AdminRole) o;

        if (!role.equals(adminRole.role)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return role.hashCode();
    }
}
```

I execute following code:

```
terminalAdminService.findAdminByRoles(Arrays.asList(new AdminRole("TERMINAL_MODERATOR"),
                        new AdminRole("MODERATOR"),
                        new AdminRole("SUPERADMIN")))




public List<TerminalAdmin> findAdminByRoles(List<AdminRole> roles) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from TerminalAdmin where adminRoles in :roles");
        query.setParameter("roles", roles);
        return query.list();
    }
```

When I execute following code:

I see error:

```
18.09.2015 08:23:30 WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 42122, SQLState: 42S22
18.09.2015 08:23:30 ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column "NON" not found; SQL statement:
select terminalad0_.admin_id as admin_id1_11_, terminalad0_.blocked as blocked2_11_, terminalad0_.registration_date as registra3_11_, terminalad0_.email as email4_11_, terminalad0_.name as name5_11_, terminalad0_.password as password6_11_, terminalad0_.phone as phone7_11_ from terminal_admin terminalad0_ cross join admin_role adminroles1_, terminal_admin_role adminrole2_ where terminalad0_.admin_id=adminroles1_.admin_id and adminroles1_.role_id=adminrole2_.role_id and ( non-qualified-property-ref  in (?)) [42122-182]
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at com.terminal.dao.admin.impl.TerminalAdminDaoImpl.findAdminByRoles(TerminalAdminDaoImpl.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findAdminByRoles(Unknown Source)
    at com.terminal.service.admin.impl.TerminalAdminServiceImpl.findAdminByRoles(TerminalAdminServiceImpl.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.findAdminByRoles(Unknown Source)
    at com.terminal.utils.EmailService.sendTerminalAddedForAdminEmail(EmailService.java:683)
    at com.terminal.service.impl.TerminalServiceImpl.saveTerminal(TerminalServiceImpl.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.saveTerminal(Unknown Source)
    at com.terminal.controller.owner.OwnerTerminalsController.saveTerminal(OwnerTerminalsController.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at com.cj.xss.XSSFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Hibernate: 
    select
        terminalad0_.admin_id as admin_id1_11_,
        terminalad0_.blocked as blocked2_11_,
        terminalad0_.registration_date as registra3_11_,
        terminalad0_.email as email4_11_,
        terminalad0_.name as name5_11_,
        terminalad0_.password as password6_11_,
        terminalad0_.phone as phone7_11_ 
    from
        terminal_admin terminalad0_ cross 
    join
        admin_role adminroles1_, terminal_admin_role adminrole2_ 
    where
        terminalad0_.admin_id=adminroles1_.admin_id 
        and adminroles1_.role_id=adminrole2_.role_id 
        and (
            {non-qualified-property-ref} in (
                ?
            )
        )
```

How to fix it?

Comment: culprit `non-qualified-property-ref`. cant find where its coming from.

Comment: @redflar3 I saw this but I have not ideas what does it mean

Comment: I am guessing the error happened because, you are asking hibernate to compare two objects (of type`AdminRoles`)..  Not sure if hibernate can do that..  Hence its describing the `adminRoles` in your `HQL` as `non-qualified-property-ref`..

Comment: @redflar3 How ti fix it?

Comment: you can try using `join` as mentioned by `Danail Alexiev`

Comment: @redflar3 His example with id

Comment: In `findAdminByRoles`, insted of passing `:roles`, you can create a `List<Long> roleIds` and populate that with IDs and pass the same to HQL

Answer (score 0):

You are directly trying to filter by an object, and I am not sure this is going to work. You should try and use a `join` in your query. Something like:

```
from TableAdmin ta left join ta.adminRoles ar where ar.id in :roleIds
```

and pass the actual ids as a parameter.

Comment: **from TerminalAdmin ta left join ta.adminRoles ar where ar.role in (:roles)**

Comment: You didn't provide join path

Answer (score 0):

this query is working:

```
from TerminalAdmin ta left join ta.adminRoles ar where ar.role in (:roles)
```

For this query - `roles` should be List of strings